# Does a function returning the value of a pointer to a new[] array leaks memory after returning the result?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I've read that we need to delete pointers after pointing it to a value address created with the keyword "new". But I need to get the values inside of an array and return it to a variable, so I wrote this function:

```
GLfloat VertexArray(Vertex<GLfloat> v1, Vertex<GLfloat> v2, Vertex<GLfloat> v3) {
    GLfloat *ArrayPtr = new GLfloat[24]{ v1.x, v1.y, v1.z, v1.w, v1.r, v1.g, v1.b, v1.a,
                                         v2.x, v2.y, v2.z, v2.w, v2.r, v2.g, v2.b, v2.a,
                                         v3.x, v3.y, v3.z, v3.w, v3.r, v3.g, v3.b, v3.a };
    return *ArrayPtr;
};
```

Is this bad? If so, is there a better way to return the entire array?

Comment: It's double-bad, because in fact you only return the first element of the array.

Comment: `is there a better way to do this?` A better way to leak memory or... What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: @eerorika "A better way to leak memory and other tips and tricks" sounds like a bestseller book!

Comment: Sorry, I thought the function was self-explanatory, but what I was trying to do is return the entire array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's bad. It's a memory leak because the allocated array is never deleted (as you said).

Here's a version that doesn't leak

```
GLfloat VertexArray(Vertex<GLfloat> v1, Vertex<GLfloat> v2, Vertex<GLfloat> v3) {
    return v1.x;
};
```

No allocation is needed for the function you wrote, because the only value you are returning is the first in your array which is `v1.x`.

Now this is a rather pointless function, so maybe your real code is more complicated than the code you posted.

Maybe you meant to write a function that returns the whole array. In that case return the pointer that you allocated `return ArrayPtr;`. In that case you still need to delete the pointer, but you can do it somewhere in the code that called this function.

Comment: Yes, my intention is to return the whole array, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Yes it definitely leaks.

You dynamically allocate and initialise 24 floats, then only use the first of them as the result (`*ArrayPtr`) and don't consider anymore the previous allocated array.

I don't know your intent, but I guess that, if your function builds such an array, you want to obtain it as a result.

```
GLfloat *
VertexArray(Vertex<GLfloat> v1, Vertex<GLfloat> v2, Vertex<GLfloat> v3) {
    GLfloat *ArrayPtr = new GLfloat[24]{ v1.x, v1.y, v1.z, v1.w, v1.r, v1.g, v1.b, v1.a,
                                         v2.x, v2.y, v2.z, v2.w, v2.r, v2.g, v2.b, v2.a,
                                         v3.x, v3.y, v3.z, v3.w, v3.r, v3.g, v3.b, v3.a };
    return ArrayPtr;
};
```